# What is the ideal padding-top value for modern, responsive HTML5 layouts?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 comes with a `padding-top` of `20px`, which is mainly used to push down the container so that the navbar doesn't hide it, but if your site or app doesn't have a navbar at the top, `60px` isn't a one-size-fits-all value. `60px` is fine for 1280x1024 and higher layouts, but anything lower than `1024px` wide and it starts to look like a little too much blank space.

I'm guessing this value will also have to be responsive. These are all the media queries in Twitter Bootstrap's responsive CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 979px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 980px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

What are the ideal padding values for each?

**Update:** How about 20px? It seems fine at 320x480 and not too shabby at 1920x1080 either.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve, of course! The cool thing is that you can have [vertical media queries](http://trentwalton.com/2012/01/11/vertical-media-queries-wide-sites/), too - maybe use those for adapting your top padding instead of looking at the viewport width?

Comment: That's interesting. I agree it can be subjective, but I'm looking for a more universal set of values, just the way the Twitter Bootstrap template itself is standardizing things.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply remove the navbar height to the padding-top to stay in the "twitter bootstrap spirit"